# How can I upload image using Storage::put on the laravel?

Tags: laravel, filesystems, storage, image-uploading, laravel-5.6

My code to upload image like this :

```
$file = $file->move($path, $fileName);
```

The code works

But I want to change it using Storage::put like this reference :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#storing-files

I try like this :

```
Storage::put($fileName, $path);
```

It does not works

I'm confused, where I must put `$file` on the code

How can I solve this problem?

**Update** :

```
$file = file of image
$path = storage_path('/app/public/product/')
$fileName = chelsea.jpg
```

So I want to save the file with name chelsea.jpg on the `/app/public/product/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy Method

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs(
'avatars', $request->user()->id
);
```

This will automatically store the files in your default configuration.

This is another example

```
Storage::put($fileName, $path);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to using this : `Storage::put($fileName, $file->getRealPath());`. But How can I set the path? I want to save the image this : `$path = storage_path('/app/public/product/');`

Comment: @SuccessMan laravel do this for you by default.  It will be saved in `storage/app/public/yourfolder`

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help